# Add a make rule to the main make of AOSP

Tags: android, makefile, android-source, android-make

I've added a new C++ subproject at `frameworks/base/cmds/myproject` and it has its own `Android.mk` file. When I run `make myproject`, it'll compile well and no problem.

However I want to add `make myproject` to the main `make`. I mean, when someone runs `make` at the root of AOSP, my project to be included as well. What should I do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need your `Android.mk` file to be called. There are various ways to do so, depending on your needs.

If you want your `myproyect` to be compiled for several of the devices you have under `device/`, then look for a common `mk` file. For example this is how Qualcomm does it, you can copy it for AOSP.

- Edit/create `device/common/common.mk`
- Make calls to that `device/common/common.mk` from every device you want to.  (This is how QCM does it: `$(call inherit-product, device/qcom/common/common.mk)`

If you want it just for a specific device:

- Let's take for granted you want to compile for `mini_emulator_x86-userdebug`, which has it's `mk` file in `device/generic/mini-emulator-x86`.
- Edit `mini_emulator_x86.mk`
- Edit or add `PRODUCT_PACKAGES` as follows:

  ```
  PRODUCT_PACKAGES += \
      myproyect
  ```

Watch out for correct indentation.

This way, when you do `source build/envsetup.sh` and `lunch mini_emulator_x86-user` and then `make`, your `myproyect.mk` will be reached.

In order to test it:

- Edit your `myproject.mk` file by adding something like this: `$(warning MyProject MK has been called`
- Call `lunch mini_emulator_x86-user`.
- `make | grep MyProject` and you don't need to wait for the whole compilation, if this outputs something in the first seconds, you're good to go.

For additional reference you may take a look at how Qualcomm organizes their `device` folder, with `common` and `base` mk files. Take a look at their open source code [here](https://source.codeaurora.org/quic/la)

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it out and get back to you for feedback.

Comment: My subproject isn't for a specific device. It should be built for all. So it seems it's `device/common/` the right place I should look into. There's no `mk` files there. Should I change `generate-packages.sh`?